# Even though my commands are almost exactly the same 2 commands work and the other 2 don't discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord.js bot but for some reason some of my commands dont work

here is my code in the main file:

```
if (command === 'help') {
    client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
} else if (command === 'clear') {
    client.commands.get('clear').run(message,args);
} else if (command === 'ban') {
  client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
} else if (command === 'kick') {
  client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
}
```

The first 2 commands work but the bottom (The kick and ban) don't work and gives me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Here is the code in the command handler for the ban commands which is not working:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'Ban',
    description: "Bans members",
    execute (message, args) { 
        message.channel.send('test')
    }
}
```

And the code in the help command handler which works is:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "this is the help command",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('This is the help command')
    }
}
```

The code is exactly the same but still the ban and kick command doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that you have named the ban command `Ban` with a capital `B`. Have you tried it with just lowercase?